# How to handle a new method in the interface that is not applicable for all classes?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I am faced with an interesting OOD problem: I have an interface with 3 methods:

```
interface TestInterface {
   String action1();
   String action2();
   String action3();
}
```

and 3 classes that implement this interface, so I have a very simple code:

```
TestInterface testInt;

if(something) {
   testInt = createObject1();
} else if(somethingElse) {
   testInt = createObject2();
} else {
   testInt = createObject3();
}


if(againSomething) {
    testInt.action1();
} else if(againSomethingElse) {
    testInt.action2();
} else {
    testInt.action3();
}
```

This works fine, however I need to add additional action, but this action only makes sense in the context of one of the classes that implement TestInterface and not in the other two, so if I would to continue the pattern, I would have to add it to the interface, and make a dummy implementation in other classes, but at least the rest of the code would look nice:

```
interface TestInterface {
   String action1();
   String action2();
   String action3();
   String action4();
}



...
if(someSpecificAction) {
   testInt.action4();
}
```

I'm not quite keen on that kind of design, so I'm looking for an alternative. I was thinking about creating another interface, just with that method, but I was wondering if I can do better than this code below ?

```
interface TestInterface {
   String action1();
   String action2();
   String action3();
}

interface NewInterface {
   String action4();

}

TestInterface testInt;
NewInterface newInt;

if(something) {
   testInt = createObject1();
} else if(somethingElse) {
   testInt = createObject2();
} else if(something3) {
   testInt = createObject3();
} else {
   testInt = createObject3();
   newInt = testInt;
}


if(againSomething) {
    testInt.action1();
} else if(againSomethingElse) {
    testInt.action2();
} else if(something) {
    testInt.action3();
} else {
   newInt.action4();
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried in your second `createObject3()`, replace it with a new method which return a new object from `class Four implements TestInterface, NewInterface { ... }` ?

Comment: Thanks, just realized I can't simply assign value from interface to another(duh), but I was able to cast it to the target interface so it was fine. This feels somehow dirty..

Not sure what I would get with class Four ? I already have class Three implements TestInterface, NewInterface { ... } which that functionality is needed.

Comment: I can give an example: Have you ever heard of ActionListener on GUI ? There are onClickListener, onLongClickListener, onCheckChangedListener (checkbox) and many many things else, they are seperated interfaces. If the framework designer just design the button component as : class Button implements ActionListener, it becomes really bad because I will have tons of method with empty body which I don't need. In your case, what happened if I never use NewInterface ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Default methods

Java can now have default methods to make it easier to add new behaviors to interfaces without modifying all implementing classes.

e.g.

```java
interface TestInterface {
    String action1();
    String action2();
    String action3();
    default String action4() { return ""; }
}
```

If there's a sensible default behavior to implement then perhaps this could be a suitable design. You might say this doesn't align with the Interface Segregation Principle, but bear in mind the implementor isin't concerned with implementing `action4` and the consumer depends on all 4 actions, so I wouldn't say it's necessarily a terrible design.

#### Feature interfaces

Alternatively you could use feature-like interfaces, like plugins, where each action has it's own interface e.g.

`interface Action4Executor { String action4(); }`

In this case however the consumer will have to use `instanceof Action4Executor` to check if the action is supported prior to invoking the behavior. Bear in mind that you need to make code discovery easy here, so that it's obvious what feature interfaces are available. For instance, you may declare other actions as nested interfaces under `TestInterface`.

#### Actions as first-class citizens

Perhaps it could make sense to model actions as messages, such as rather than
being methods, actions are objects e.g.

```java
interface TestInterface {
    String executeAction(Action action);
}
```

In this case you'd have to document in the interface what should happen when actions aren't supported for instance, or you may add a `boolean supportsAction(Action action)` in the interface as well.

#### Conclusion

Hopefully that gives you some design ideas. It's hard to tell what should be the proper design without knowing more about the problem domain...